# Generating XML SAML with signature using xmlsec1

Tags: linux, centos, single-sign-on, xml

I am trying generate XML SAML with signature to SSO, but I have a problem and I don't know what is wrong. I don't have experience with Linux. I generated privkey and cacert with lib openssl.

Next step, I install lib xmlsec1:

`yum install xmlsec1`

yum install xmlsec1-openssl

My test:

`# xmlsec1 --sign --privkey-pem home/test/privkey.pem,home/test/cacert.pem --output /home/test/test.xml /home/test/tosign.xml`

Error:

`func=xmlSecBufferReadFile:file=buffer.c:line=477:obj=unknown:subj=fopen:error=7:io function failed:filename=home/test/privkey.pem;errno=2 func=xmlSecGCryptAppKeyLoad:file=app.c:line=162:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecBufferReadFile:error=1:xmlsec library function failed:filename=home/test/privkey.pem func=xmlSecAppCryptoSimpleKeysMngrKeyAndCertsLoad:file=crypto.c:line=118:obj=unknown:subj=xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoad:error=1:xmlsec library function failed:uri=home/test/privkey.pem Error: failed to load private key from "home/test/privkey.pem". Error: keys manager creation failed`

I tried with other example lib xmlsec and other privekey, but errors are the same.

Comment: Fixing the obvious typos in your command would be a good start.

Comment: If you mean slash, I tried with and  without slashes.
/home/test/
home/test